# How to add an empty row and assign "None" value to in a dataframe? I want to do it dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to add an empty row to multiple dataframes and export to CSV.

My wanted outcome is as follow :

1. Current File looks like this :
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqgjy.png
2. Wanted Outcome
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiE4d.png

I have more than 200 files and some have 47 columns, some have 60 columns, some have 50 columns.

How can I add one empty row for all my files dynamically using Pandas?

Appreciate the help as i cant find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3, 'cat'], ['d', 4, 'dog'],['h',1,'impala']],columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal'])
df.loc[1] = np.nan
```

This might work as well:

```
#load dataframe
df.loc[1] = ""
```

Comment: I think this will not insert a new row at start, but rather replace second row with blanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code...
Note:

1. Get list of all dataframes you want to convert to CSV. I have created 3 dummy dataframes and added them to a list. Assuming first row in your files is the header, not data
2. Assign names to the CSV files that you want to write the data to. Assuming you want to write each DF to a separate CSV as they are of different sizes
3. Use for loop to iterate through each file, use the name and write to CSV for each DF you have

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'End1':[1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'End2':[1,2,3,4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Start3': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'End3':[1,2,3,4]})

dfList = [df1, df2, df3] #Get the list of all dataframes you want to write to CSV
csvnames = ['firstdf', 'seconddf', 'thirddf'] #Assign string names to the CSV files you want to create

for i, dftemp in enumerate(dfList): #Iterate through each dataframe
    insertdf = pd.DataFrame([[""] * len(dftemp.columns)], columns=dftemp.columns) #Create empty DF with 1 line of <blanks>
    insertdf = insertdf.append(dftemp, ignore_index=True) # Append new DF
    insertdf.to_csv(csvnames[i] + ".csv", index = False) # Create one CSV for each DF
```

**Output**
This will create 3 files with names as `firstdf.csv`, `seconddf.csv`, `thirddf.csv` with the data in DF, but with a single blank line like below

[image]